# Serialize a nested array of objects using serde

Tags: rust, serde

From a struct describing a puzzle grid, I'd like to be able to serialize a nested array:

```rust
struct Grid {
  display: String,
  solution: String,
  width: usize,
  height: usize,
}
```

Assuming a struct of `Grid { display: "????", solution: "1234", width: 2, height: 2 }`, I'd like the output to look like the following (in JSON):

```json
[
  [
    {
      "display": "?",
      "solution": "1"
    },
    {
      "display": "?",
      "solution": "2"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "display": "?",
      "solution": "3"
    },
    {
      "display": "?",
      "solution": "4"
    }
  ]
]
```

My initial draft implementation looks like this:

```rust
impl<'a> Serialize for Grid<'a> {
    fn serialize<S: Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        let mut columns = serializer.serialize_seq(Some(self.height))?;
        for column_index in 0..self.height {
            let mut column = columns.serialize_seq(Some(self.width))?;
            for row_index in 0..self.width {
                let mut cell = column.serialize_map(Some(2))?;
                let cell_index = column_index * self.height + row_index;
                cell.serialize_entry("display", self.display.chars().nth(cell_index).unwrap())?;
                cell.serialize_entry("solution", self.solution.chars().nth(cell_index).unwrap())?;

                cell.end()?;
            }

            column.end()?;
        }

        columns.end()
    }
}
```

However, `SerializeSeq` does not expose another `serialize_seq` method for further nesting. How can I serialize a nested array out of one struct like this?

Comment: Writing a custom serializer is probably the best option in the long run, but I'd imagine it'd be easy (if inefficient) to write a `struct Item { display: String, solution: String }` and then a method on `Grid` that returns and/or serializes a `Vec<Vec<Item>>`.

Comment: you need a second structure to implement serialize on it too, and maybe a third in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A helper struct Cell with *display* and *solution* as fields will make the serialization easier. Then, you can construct a list of Cells in a functional way with the iterator adapters including *zip* and *map* from the solution and display values of the grid. Then, use the *chunks* adapter to convert the one-dimension vector into a two-dimension vector by the row size. At last, use the macro json! to generate the json string.

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::json;

struct Grid {
  display: String,
  solution: String,
  width: usize,
  height: usize,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Cell {
    display: char,
    solution: char,
}

fn main() {
    let grid = Grid { display: "????".to_string(), solution: "1234".to_string(), width: 2, height: 2 };

    let cells :Vec<Cell> = grid.display.chars().zip(grid.solution.chars()).map(|(a, b)| Cell {display: a, solution: b} ).collect();
    let rows : Vec<&[Cell]>= cells.chunks(grid.width).collect();

    print!("{:#}", json!(rows));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20serde%3A%3A%7BDeserialize%2C%20Serialize%7D%3B%0Ause%20serde_json%3A%3Ajson%3B%0A%0Astruct%20Grid%20%7B%0A%20%20display%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20solution%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20width%3A%20usize%2C%0A%20%20height%3A%20usize%2C%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Serialize%2C%20Deserialize)%5D%0Astruct%20Cell%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20display%3A%20char%2C%0A%20%20%20%20solution%3A%20char%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20grid%20%3D%20Grid%20%7B%20display%3A%20%22%3F%3F%3F%3F%22.to_string()%2C%20solution%3A%20%221234%22.to_string()%2C%20width%3A%202%2C%20height%3A%202%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20cells%20%3AVec%3CCell%3E%20%3D%20grid.display.chars().zip(grid.solution.chars()).map(%7C(a%2C%20b)%7C%20Cell%20%7Bdisplay%3A%20a%2C%20solution%3A%20b%7D%20).collect()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20rows%20%3A%20Vec%3C%26%5BCell%5D%3E%3D%20cells.chunks(grid.width).collect()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20print!(%22%7B%3A%23%7D%22%2C%20json!(rows))%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: I ended up going with this solution, though I can't say I'm terribly pleased with it compared to being able to do it without the helper struct. Oh well -- Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You need a couple of helper structs to represent a row and a cell:

```
use serde::*; // 1.0.130
use serde::ser::*;

struct Grid {
  display: String,
  solution: String,
  width: usize,
  height: usize,
}

impl Serialize for Grid {
    fn serialize<S: Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        let mut rows = serializer.serialize_seq (Some (self.height))?;
        for idx in 0..self.height {
            rows.serialize_element (&Row { grid: self, start_idx: idx * self.width })?;
        }
        rows.end()
    }
}

struct Row<'a> {
    grid: &'a Grid,
    start_idx: usize,
}

impl<'a> Serialize for Row<'a> {
    fn serialize<S: Serializer> (&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        let mut row = serializer.serialize_seq (Some (self.grid.width))?;
        for idx in 0..self.grid.width {
            row.serialize_element (&Cell { grid: self.grid, idx: self.start_idx + idx })?;
        }
        row.end()
    }
}

struct Cell<'a> {
    grid: &'a Grid,
    idx: usize,
}

impl<'a> Serialize for Cell<'a> {
    fn serialize<S: Serializer> (&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        let mut cell = serializer.serialize_map (Some (2))?;
        cell.serialize_entry ("display", &self.grid.display.chars().nth (self.idx).unwrap())?;
        cell.serialize_entry ("solution", &self.grid.solution.chars().nth (self.idx).unwrap())?;
        cell.end()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa2b9b361ad54fbff5c2e89ec08fed4d)